# Does EOS support HD wallet?

Tags: wallet

I am wandering does EOS support HD wallet.

If not, how to create and manage key pairs of EOS wallet?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean hardware wallet, and yes, ledger supports EOS thanks to the $50k bounty BP Cypherglass but up.

[Source](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008913653-EOS-EOS-)

Also [EOS New York](https://medium.com/eos-new-york/eos-new-york-roadmap-eos-hardware-wallet-community-meetup-plan-more-f4db48477d09) will be coming out with a hardware wallet soon.

In the meantime, I recommend the [desktop wallet Scatter](https://get-scatter.com/)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is useful but my question is about Hierarchical Deterministic wallet.

Comment: Scatter uses seeds.